# Eliminar fila de un datatable con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Tengo una tabla (datatable) creada con jquery y en cada fila tengo un botón de eliminar para que se elimine la fila correspondiente.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que si mi tabla tiene más de una página no elimina la fila de la página actual. En cambio si solo tiene una unica fila, la elimina correctamente.

Adjunto el código que tengo:

```
$(document).on('click','.eliminar',function(){

                      var idPos = $(this).attr('id');

                      var row = $(this).parent().parent();

                       var ref= row.find("td").eq(1).html();

                      $this = $(this);

                      var dtRow =  $this.parents('tr');

                      var conf = confirm("¿Desea excluir esta operacion con referencia " + ref+ "?");

                      if(conf == true){

                             var table = $('#operacionesTR').DataTable();

                             table.row((dtRow[0].rowIndex)-1).remove().draw(false);

                      }
         });
```

También he intentado probar esto, pero no he obtenido resultado:

```
table.row((dtRow[0].rowIndex)-1, {page:'current'}).remove().draw(false);
```

Espero vuestra ayuda, Muchas gracias!!

Comment: como creas la tabla ? ,  si es una libreria de jquery, debe tener una instruccion para eliminar algun renglon.

Comment: La estoy creando con la libreria de datatables y en principio el remove la elimina, pero cuando tengo más de una página en mi tabla no elimina correctamente..